# ClipsToBounds on a rotated superview

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, rotation, transform

I am adding a subview on a rotated superview and want it to clip to the superviews bounds.

I know that the bounds are the rectangle around the rotated view and by knowing that I DON'T want to clip it to the superviews bounds but I want it to clip at the actual borders of the rotated superview.

How is that done?